# Xamarin vs. Mono vs. Monodevelop

Tags: c#, mono, cross-platform, xamarin, monodevelop

What is the relationship between [Xamarin](http://www.xamarin.com) and [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)(Are they the same product)?

Is the Monodevelop IDE related to Mono?

Comment: Mono is the open source project, core of the cross platform .NET initiative. Xamarin is a brand for its commercial product lines (Mac, iOS, and Android). They are closely related to each other as many Xamarin employees work on Mono, but they are different, and I believe that was the reason why they rebranded MonoTouch and Mono for Android to Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android. The line between open source and commercial is never clearer. MonoDevelop is of course for Mono, and Xamarin Studio is for Xamarin.

Comment: Quote from their webpage -- "Xamarin Studio is a bundle of MonoDevelop along with Xamarin iOS/Android plugins and branding".

Comment: Can try Visual Studio Code now - https://code.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 50):

Xamarin is primarily a platform for developing mobile applications (Android and iPhone) using C#.

The Mono project is an open-source port of the .NET framework. It is most commonly used to run .NET under Linux. From a performance standpoint, it runs about 50% (on average) as fast as the .NET framework.

MonoDevelop is an open-source C# IDE analagous to Eclipse or Visual Studio.

Miguel de Icaza was the primary developer for Mono and is one of the founders/owners of Xamarin.

- https://xamarin.com/
- http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page
- http://monodevelop.com/

Comment: Why does stock MonoDevelop display news from Xamarin on the start page?

Comment: @AaronFranke - Xamarin is a primary developer for it. Xamarin Studio also just appears to be a rebranding of MonoDevelop (according to Wikipedia anyway...)

Comment: You can also develop applications for Xamarin using F# - see https://github.com/fsprojects/Fabulous