# Best possibility to code c# on os x?

Tags: c#, macos

I want to learn C#. Due to I am an Mac and OS X User I have searched for an opportunity to code C# on my Mac.

I read a lot about Xamarin, Mono and Mono Develope and now I am a little bit confused what is the right choice for me, if I want to learn and code C# on my mac.

So can you help me? Where are the differences between the three mentioned above and which should I choose?

Comment: Hi Ari, this isn't really a Stackoverflow question... you should instead just google for some information. You can then come here when you have actual implementation problems. In any case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589011/xamarin-vs-mono-vs-monodevelop so this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want to learn C# install the Mono Framework and Mono Develop.

Mono is just the framework itself

MonoDevelop is the IDE based on Mono for programming with Mono

Xamarin Studio is the commercial version of Mono

http://www.mono-project.com/download/

http://www.monodevelop.com/

However, Mono may not have all features that the current .NET version has, nor may C# give you all language features that it has on MS systems.

This is because the mono framework is much behind the original .NET framework.

For learning the basics, it is sufficient though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to try Visual Studio Code that's available for Mac OS X.